# Folding a list of elements into a set of elements

Tags: haskell, set

I want to fold a list into a set, but my implementation seems to require that the list is already a set. `Element` has an `Ord` instance. Imports are correct.

```
listToSet :: [Element] -> Set Element
listToSet d = foldl' insert empty d
```

`d` should already be a set here, so this of course gives a type error, can I use `foldl'` to create a set from a list? Do I first need to "cast" the list of `Element`s to a list of sets of length one with each one of the `Element`s?

Error:

```
Assignment3.hs:201:39: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Element' with `Set Element'
      Expected type: [Set Element]
        Actual type: [Element]
    * In the third argument of foldl', namely `d'
      In the expression: foldl' insert empty d
      In an equation for `listToSet':
          listToSet d = foldl' insert empty d
    |
201 | listToSet d = foldl' insert empty d
    |
```

Comment: Probably it should be `foldl' (flip insert)`

Comment: Why don't you just use `fromList` function from `Data.Set` module?

Comment: @Redu As an exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`foldl' :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-) has as first parameter a function of type `b -> a -> b`, you thus should provide first the `Set` to update, then the element to insert, and it then generates a new `Set`.

The [**`insert :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Set.html#v:insert) however takes the parameters in the *opposite* way: it first takes the element to insert, and then `Set` to update.

You thus can use [**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) to "flip the parameters", and thus construct a function that has parameters in the order the `foldl'` can process, so we can define the function like:

```
import Data.Set(empty, insert)
import Data.List(foldl')

listToSet :: (Foldable f, Ord e) => f e -> Set e
listToSet = foldl' (flip insert) empty
```

Note that what you here aim to define already exists: the `Data.Set` module has a [**`fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Set.html#v:fromList) function to generate a `Set a` out of an `[a]`.

Answer (score 4):

You are accidentally referring to `Data.Set.foldl'` instead of `Data.List.foldl'`. You need to import both modules and then disambiguate:

```
listToSet :: [Int] -> Set Int
listToSet d = Data.List.foldl' (flip Data.Set.insert) empty d
```

Even better, use qualifed imports:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.List

listToSet :: [Int] -> S.Set Int
listToSet d = foldl' (flip S.insert) S.empty d
```

Or even better, directly use `S.fromList`: it's already present in the library, so there's no point in reinventing the wheel (unless as an exercise).